# Gson Help - Trying to get the first value (key) of JSON using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Trying to get the fist value (key) of JSON using Gson lib, any help is good.
Looking to get `-K_63RGSCZra1jVeDrmT` from the JSON and want to save it in String variable.

Here is mine code and output :

```
gson.toJson(dataSnapshot.getValue());
Log.d(tag, "gson: " + gson.toJson(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
```

output:

```
{"-K_63RGSCZra1jVeDrmT":{"name":"Joseph witman","email":"jwitman@gmail.com"}}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: The question is, I have this output, but want to get the fist key, "-K_63RGSCZra1jVeDrmT" then store it in a string

Comment: Take time to read this post on how to compose a good SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
String json = "{\"-K_63RGSCZra1jVeDrmT\":{\"name\":\"Joseph witman\",\"email\":\"jwitman@gmail.com\"}}";
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = jp.parse(json);
JsonObject root = element.getAsJsonObject();
```

Since `JsonObject.entrySet()` contains all key values you could extract them in the following way;

```
for (Entry<String, JsonElement> e : root.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey());
}
```

Comment: I am trying to grab the value, by code, not by me typing the value in.

Comment: the first value is created automatically, by code, now am trying to grab it to store it into a string.

Comment: Thank you,, that worked,, I been working on this for 3 days now, before i asked for help,, just couldnt figure it out, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code to get key :

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jobj = parser.parse(new FileReader("Filepath_JSON")).getAsJsonObject();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jobj.entrySet();
    for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
        Person prsn = gson.fromJson(jobj.getAsJsonObject(entry.getKey()), Person.class);
        prsn.setId(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println("id :  " + prsn.getId());

    }
```

Here is Pojo Person class :

```
class Person {

private String id;
private String name;
private String email;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
} }
```

I run the code and it works fine.

Cheers.